# send message from my personal telegram account to a telegram bot owned by other person

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I m trying to send a message from my personal account to telegram bot that I dont know his tokken with python or php, I have searched a lot but I didn find how to do that and I dont know if its possible or no

I m used to send messages from my bot to my account or to other users using this code:

```
import requests
TOKEN = " "
chat_id = " "
message = "hello"
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}"
print(requests.get(url).json())
```

but how to send message to bot that I dont have its token

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, Bot's can never talk to other bots.

The only option is to make use of the Core API, make your own Telegram client so you can programmatically talk with your own user to a Bot.

For example, you can use Telethon for that.